# Is there a cipher that encrypts words into different words?

Tags: encryption

I've been looking at the various types of ciphers and I can't seem to find something I want or if it's even possible.

For example the text is "London2234", when run through the cipher, it encrypts into something like "Marble2234" where a person who doesn't have the cipher doesn't see it as garbage but sees it as another word where they can't make any context of.

Like a dictionary cipher of some sort? Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing symmetric encryption algorithms with whole words](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41529/implementing-symmetric-encryption-algorithms-with-whole-words)

Comment: Seems simple to me: encrypt using any encryption algorithm of your choice, break the result into groups of, say, 16 bits, then use each 16-bit-chunk as an index into a dictionary.